# PowerShell Error: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PlatformParameters" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to automatically upload a CSV into PowerBi using the Git repository PowerBIPS.  I can't seem to get past this error:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PlatformParameters" and the argument count: "1".

With the help of the article linked here (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-a-power-bi-app-to-upload-csv-files-to-a-dataset/), I believe I have found a viable solution to solve this.  However, I am running into an error I can't seem to figure out.

I have customized the code from the original article to fit my current situation (outlined in the code below).  I am able to run the code up until the "send data to PowerBi comment" where this error is raised.

I have tried referencing the Git documentation to help with this issue, but have found no luck.  I have a feeling it has to do with the authentication piece of connecting to PowerBi.

```cs
while ($true) {
    # Iterate each CSV file and send to PowerBI
    Get-ChildItem "$currentPath\CSVData" -Filter "*.csv" | % {
        $file = $_

        #Import csv and add column with filename
        $data = Import-Csv $file.FullName |
                select @{Label="File";Expression={$file.Name}}, *

        # Send data to PowerBI
        $data | Out-PowerBI -DataSetName "CSVSales" -TableName "Sales" -Types @{
            "Sales.OrderDate"   = "datetime";
            "Sales.SalesAmount" = "double";
            "Sales.Freight"     = "double"
        } -BatchSize 300 -Verbose

        # Archive the file
        Move-Item $file.FullName "$currentPath\CSVData\Archive\" -Force
    }

    Write-Output "Sleeping..."
    Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

```
VERBOSE: Getting the Authentication Token

VERBOSE: Using default authentication flow

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PlatformParameters" and the argument
count: "1".
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerBIPS\2.0.3.1\PowerBIPS.psm1:299 char:16
+ ... pltParams = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirector ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Looks like incompatibility between this cmdlet and ADAL library. Make sure you are using the right version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll`.

Comment: It appears you are correct!  Thank you for the quick response Andrey.

Comment: How did you solve it?  I have the same problem but can't seem to connect the docs on the versions.   in powershell i got all of this using Install-Module Az.  which in turn has it's own copy of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll .   that has a verison of 3.19 . is that good?  if not, how to I change the version of that file without messing with the Az PS module?